# tool to format java code in the repository without using IDE

Tags: java, code-formatting

I am working in a java project in which most of the code is not properly formatted. I am trying to find a tool which executes the formatter in the code ie) Is there any tool to format the java code which was pushed into the repository?

Comment: Based on which rules you want to format? Would be using Eclipse from commandline an option?

Comment: You might look at using a tool like `astyle`; see: http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Do you use maven in your project? If that is the case I can give you an option.

Comment: @malaguna, I'm using Maven. Give me an option!

Comment: @D0dger I am going to write an answer ...

Comment: Does astyle gaurantee that a formatted program still compiles and still provides the same execution behaviour?  Given that it doesn't know the exact language syntax of what it is formatting, how can it make that gaurantee?

Answer (score 3):

There is a maven plugin called `formatter-maven-plugin` that you can found [here](https://github.com/revelc/formatter-maven-plugin). With this plugin you can use a formatting goal as follows:

```
mvn java-formatter:format
```

In order to use this goal you have to configure your `pom.xml`. In this [page](http://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/format-mojo.html) you have info about how to use it, but a simple plugin configuration could be the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        ... your specific options here ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi @malaguna, This worked for me. Thank you so much. Can I apply this code format during git-commit? Many times it happens that, people do not execute mvn commands before pushing the code. If somehow I can add this as a git commit hook, it can help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who don't want to use maven or only want to format a set of files and have Eclipse installed. They could use Eclipse formatter from command line as

For Windows (one line)

```
%ECLIPSE_HOME%\eclipsec.exe -vm "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" \
-nosplash -consolelog -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter \
-verbose -config .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs \
Foo.java Bar.java
```

This solution uses the formatting rules defined on the Eclipse project level. The file `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` then contains entries for `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.*`. It will not work if the formatting rules are defined on workspace level.

I assume you want to run the formatting only once. In that case you can enable before the execution the `Enable project specific settings` on the properties for `Java code style -> Formatter`. Only confirm this setting by clicking on `OK` will store the workspace rules in the file `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`. If you disable this setting after the execution the rules will be removed.

Comment: Thanks SubOptimal. What if i use custom formatter. because we are importing formatter as xml.

Comment: @Shriram Have a look to my updated answer. I add a short explanation how the formatting rules in Eclipse can be used. If you have an XML file with in Eclipse compatible format you could import this file in Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Our [Java Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/JavaFormatter.html) is a standalone and scriptable tool that will format individual files, or complete sets of files as defined by a project file.

It is based on a language accurate parser and prettyprinter; it can't break your code.

Given that formatting a file once, and formatting it again, will produce the same result, one might wonder whether there should be a do-it-once switch.   Formatting is fast enough so that doing it once before each checking won't hurt, even it the file is already well-formatted.